# ActionBar overflow not appearing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I've followed along with the tutorial on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html and they mention the Action Overflow but they do not mention how to use it within your project.

I've seen some answers right here on SO but they say to get menu items to show up in the overflow menu (the menu that gets opened with you tap on the 3 horizontal tiny squares on the top right of your apps window) you need to set android:showAsAction, I have tried setting showAsAction with all possible values like always, ifRoom, never and um, collapseActionView but the overflow squares menu never shows and instead the popup menu shows on the bottom of the screen *only* when I press the menu button.

How do I get my icons in the Action Overflow menu (the menu you press on the actionbar with the squares)?

Comment: does your device have a hardware menubutton?

Comment: It does and I've heard people say it's by design if you have hard menu button but I currently have about 10 apps I bought from the play store that still display the overflow squares thingy. @Raghunandan how can I force it on there?

Comment: And why don't they make it easy for us to force it? It would be good for debugging to see what things look like without having to go buy a bunch of different phones with and without certain buttons.

Answer (score 3):

If your device has a dedicated menu button which you have indicated then the overflow menu will not shown. the menu button on your phone is the overflow menu

Comment: Thanks @tyczj. The menu button sucks to be honest, and it should show because I have about 10 apps (not my apps, just ones from the store), that do have the top actionbar overflow thingy. Is there a way to force it?

Comment: There is no way to force the icon specifically, the only forcing you can do it in your menu use `showActionAs` `never`. that puts the menu item in the overflow menu but like I said if you have an menu button the overflow icon will not show in the aactionbar. The only option you have is to create your own view that looks like an actionbar with the icons in it

Comment: Argh. I hate restrictions! Thanks for yr help :)